# Order by sub select

Tags: order-by, subquery

I have 3 tables: `articles`, `paragraphs`, `notes`

An `article` may have many `paragraphs`, and a `paragraph` may have 0 or 1 note.

Now I want to find all notes belong to an article:

```
select * from notes 
where paragraph_id in 
   (select id from paragraphs where article_id='111' order by "order" asc)
order by ???
```

It can get all notes for article `111`, but the order is not correct. I want the items in the result set have the same order as the order of `id` in the sub select.

But how? I have tried for a while, but not get the correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could convert to an `inner join`:

```
select  n.*
from    notes n
join    paragraphs p
on      n.paragraph_id = p.id
where   p.article_id = '111'
order by
        p."order"
```

Comment: `notes` doesn't have an `article_id`, it only has a `paragraph_id`

Comment: Right, that should've been `p.article_id`, answer edited

Answer (score 0):

The inner `order by` is not necessary at all. May be it also confuses the database, not only me.

```
select 
  n.*
from 
  paragraps p,
  notes n
where
  p.article_id = 111
  and n.paragraph_id = p.id
order by p."order"
```

Comment: But the questions asks to order by `paragraphs.order`